# Метод для замеров времени выполнения callable, чтобы тестировать эффективность алгоритмов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Скажите пожалуйста почему не работает код?

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( const int i )
{
    std::cout << ( i + i ) << std::endl;
}

int bar( const double d )
{
    const int ret = static_cast< int >( d + 0.7 );
    std::cout << ( ret ) << std::endl;
    return ret;
}

template< class Ret,
          class Callable,
          class ...Args >
Ret callAnyProducer( Callable callable, Args&&... args )
{
    // auto start = current_time_point();
    Ret ret = callable( std::forward( args... ) );
    // auto duration = start - current_time_point()
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    //getExecutionTime( foo, 1 );

    auto a = getExecutionTime( bar, 3.2 );
    return 0;
}
```

Идея такая - сделать метод для замеров времени выполнения callable, чтобы тестировать эффективность алгоритмов (в учебных целях).

Спасибо.

Comment: Наверное, потому что `getExecutionTime` не объявлено/определено?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, навскидку -

```
template< class Callable,
          class ...Args >
auto getExecutionTime( Callable callable, Args&&... args )
{
    //auto start = current_time_point();
    auto ret = callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //auto duration = start - current_time_point()
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    //auto a = getExecutionTime( foo, 1 );

    auto a = getExecutionTime( bar, 3.2 );
    return 0;
}
```

Только с возвращаемым типом `void` надо немного повозиться... Например,

```
template< class Callable,
          class ...Args >
auto getExecutionTime( Callable callable, Args&&... args )
{
    if constexpr(is_same<invoke_result<Callable,Args...>::type,void>::value)
    {
        //auto start = current_time_point();
        callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        //auto duration = start - current_time_point()
    }
    else
    {
        //auto start = current_time_point();
        auto ret = callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        //auto duration = start - current_time_point()
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: По-хорошему нужно еще как-то учитывать возврат ссылок... На вскидку, должна сработать замена `auto` на `decltype(auto)` в обоих местах, и `return ret;` на `return decltype(ret)(ret);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вполне возможно - по большому счету, у меня просто набросок решения...